# HTML & CSS created webpage should not change/adjust position of elements on resizing browser

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am a beginner to HTML and CSS. I am trying to make a very basic webpage in HTML.
I am facing an issue. When I resize browser, the position of navigation items automatically change. Is there any way to fix there position?

```css
@font-face { font-family: sansation; src: url('sanslight.ttf'); }

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    font-family: sansation;
    color:white;
}

/* ---------Header-------------*/
.container{
    max-width: 920px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:10px 21px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid darkgrey;
    background-color: white;
    
}

.topnav {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.topnav a{
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-left: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #ff9900;
}

.topnav a:hover{
    background-color: #ffad33;
    font-style: italic;
    border: none;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    border-bottom:  4px solid #e68a00;
}
.topnav a.active{
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #ff9900;
    font-style: normal;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #e68a00;    
}

.logo{
    margin-top: 2px;
}



/*-------CONTENT-------*/
.slideshow{
    max-width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid darkgrey;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 21px;
}

h2{
    width: 923px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 10px 21px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #ff9900;
    
}

.doctor{
    color:black;
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 100%;  
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    border-width: 2px;
}

.doctor tr{
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.demo ,table ,td{
    color: darkgray;
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 33%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Online Doctor Support</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    </head>
    
<body>
<header>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" style="width:150px;height:auto;"></a>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="about.htm">About</a>
        <a href="#">Review</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div></div>
</header>
<div class="slideshow">
    <img src="images/ste.png">
    </div>
    
    <h2>Welcome!</h2>

    
<table class="doctor">
    <tr>
        <th><img src="images/doctor.png" style="width:150px;height:150px"></th>
        <th><img src="images/doctor1.png" style="width:150px;height:150px"></th>
        <th><img src="images/doctor3.png" style="width:150px;height:150px"></th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><font size="35px">Doctor1</font></td>
        <td><font size="35px">Doctor2</font></td>
        <td><font size="35px">Doctor3</font></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    
<table class="demo">
    <tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    
    </body>
</html>
```

I am really sorry if there are mistakes in my codding ;)

Here is how my page look when I resize browser : https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAs83.jpg

Comment: You have required to use @media query

Comment: Tahir Hamza when You use @media query every resolution then Your work will we done as You wish

Comment: @AshishShahi Thanks for the help :) Can you please help me with @ media query? Where should I add it?

Comment: You add media query in css

Comment: Kamaza https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp you watch these link you have a idea how can we add media query in css

Comment: this code is work please Upvote My commeant

Answer (score 1):

This is because you've given a width of `100%` to `.container`.
If you do not want the elements to change position on window resize, consider giving a fixed width to your container (This is not recommended though and goes against responsive design principles).

Once it is fixed on desktop browser, then perhaps you can look into [Responsive Web Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) (using `@media` queries) to support all sorts of screens and resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @font-face { font-family: sansation; src: url('sanslight.ttf'); }

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    font-family: sansation;
    color:white;
}

/* ---------Header-------------*/
.container{
    max-width: 920px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:10px 21px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid darkgrey;
    background-color: white;

}

.topnav {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.topnav a{
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-left: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #ff9900;
}

.topnav a:hover{
    background-color: #ffad33;
    font-style: italic;
    border: none;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    border-bottom:  4px solid #e68a00;
}
.topnav a.active{
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #ff9900;
    font-style: normal;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #e68a00;    
}

.logo{
    margin-top: 2px;
}



/*-------CONTENT-------*/
.slideshow{
    max-width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid darkgrey;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 21px;
}

h2{
    width: 923px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 10px 21px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #ff9900;

}

.doctor{
    color:black;
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 100%;  
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    border-width: 2px;
}

.doctor tr{
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;

}

.demo ,table ,td{
    color: darkgray;
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 33%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: inherit;
    text-align: center;   
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
p {
    min-height: 100px;
}
}
```

---

You write to css these type to add media query and design Your Page as Your wish